# PLY :How does solve the following duality problem

Tags: sql, python-3.x, parsing, ply

I am writing a SQL parser, one rule in my parser like this.

```
predicate : value_expression in LPAREN expressions RPAREN
          | value_expression
```

When parser SQL contains "in" keyword like "Select * from t where a in (1,2,3)",It will always do
'predicate -> value_expression'.
how to make it do like 'predicate -> value_expression in value_expression'

how to make it do like 'predicate -> value_expression in value_expression'

Comment: 1) You're missing left paren and right paren.

Comment: 2) Predicate has no value_expression rule.

Comment: sorry, I add left paren and right paren in example, value_expression is rule which i defined

Comment: Your main problem here is that value_expression isn't a predicate.